# Show div instead with .hover or .mouseover ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, hover

I have a image and on mouse hover i want to add a description like box or smthing like that.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".desc").hover(function(){
            $(this).show(".abc");
        });
    });
</script>
```

.desc is my div where picture is, .abc is my div where description is.

.abc on the page load has to be hidden

help ?

EDIT ::

i solve this way

```
$('.desc').on({
            mouseover: function() {
                $(this).find('span').fadeIn(200);
            },

            mouseout: function() {
                $(this).find('span').stop().fadeOut(200);
            },
        })
```

where span  <`span class="d-none">  <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /> </span>`

and span css is `display:none;`

thank you again for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the div you want to show. This is done by the following line `$(".abc").show();`.
The code below should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".desc").hover(function(){
        $(".abc").show();
    });
});
```

**Side note:**
The `this` keyword inside the callback function for the `.hover` event refers to the element(s) it was triggered upon. In this case, it is any element that matches `$(".desc")`.